How to change the text in the tooltip related to the Dokan plugin badges?
I am looking to change the text in the tooltip of one of the dokan plugin badges. I want to remove the phrase "had their store featured". Thank
<aside id="dokan_seller_badges-4b21e65" class="widget dokan-store-widget woocommerce dokan_widget widget_dokan_seller_badges"><div class="woocommerce dokan_widget widget_dokan_seller_badges"><div class="dokan-seller-badge-list"><div class="container tips" title="" data-original-title="featured: Had their store featured">
                <img src="https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/dokan-business/modules/seller-badge/assets/images/badges/vendor-featured.svg" alt="featured">
                
                </div></div></div></aside>

I searched different parts of the code of this plugin, but I did not find the part where the desired expression is present.
